# Laravel blade assign css class conditionally

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to add a css class condionally in my blade body tag by adding auth-container class if url is either /login or /auth/reset-password

so i have

```
<body> //here add class
```

So i have tried

```
@if(in_array(  , ['login','/auth/reset-password']) )//stuck here
   <body class="auth-container">
@else()
    <body> //no class
@endif()
```

Am stuck on how to figure out if the url is `/login or /auth/reset-password` hence add the class `auth-container`

Comment: what laravel version are you using? are your routes named?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `is` method in your request can check if the url is matching a pattern. You may use the * character as a wildcard:

```
<body @if(Request::is('login/*') || Request::is('auth/reset-password')) class="auth-container" @endif>
```

Comment: Thanks this works if i may also ask which one can i use to negate the above is there not to replace is

Comment: to negate, just the `!` so `!Request::is('login/')` for example